# I downcasted my variable but I cannot call the function of the new class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I created a few prototype cells in my iOS Swift project, and I am now trying to initialize the cells depending on how the form uses the cells.

Here's what the cells look like:

[image]

I am now attempting to create the form such that it starts with two disclosure cells (the cell that has "Detail >" on the right), followed by one with a switch.

Each of these prototypes are linked to their own individual classes.

Here's how I generate the cells:

```
var cell : UITableViewCell?
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0,1:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reportCellWithDisclosureIndicator", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reportCellWithDisclosureIndicator
        case 2:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reportCellWithSwitch", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reportCellWithSwitch
        default:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reportCellWithDisclosureIndicator", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reportCellWithDisclosureIndicator
        }
    default:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reportCellWithDisclosureIndicator", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reportCellWithDisclosureIndicator
    }

...
switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    cell?.textLabel!.text = "Medications"
    cell?.detailTextLabel!.text = "None"
case 1:
    cell?.textLabel!.text = "Allergies"
    cell?.detailTextLabel!.text = "None"
case 2:
if(cell is reportCellWithSwitch) {
   cell?.configure("Smoking")    // PROBLEM LINE HERE
} ...
```

The function `configure` is a member of the `reportCellWithSwitch` class. The problem I have is when I try to configure that specific cell.

This is the `configure` function in the `reportCellWithSwitch` class:

```
import UIKit

public class reportCellWithSwitch: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellSwitch: UISwitch!
    public func configure(text: String) {
        // This serves to replace the title in the prototype cell
        titleLabel!.text = text
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I use the `configure` function?

Do I have to declare specific individual variables per cell type?

Should I write a general class that holds all of my configurations and call the functions as needed?

Any ideas and insights would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you mean to have 4 sections instead for rows? Because you switch statement you are using indexPath.section

Comment: Actually the form has multiple sections. I just shortened the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: To clarify, the form (or table) has multiple sections, which in themselves contain multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(cell is reportCellWithSwitch) {
   let  castcell = cell as! reportCellWithSwitch
   castcell.configure("Smoking")    
}
```

You should cast the cell(`UITableviewCell`) to castcell( `reportCellWithSwitch`) first,because UITableviewCell does not have the function of `configure`

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the following error:
Cannot invoke 'configure' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Comment: Done. I was actually in the process of posting the code when you made the comment, haha.

Comment: Hey so this worked, I just had to return 'castcell' instead of 'cell'. If you update your answer to add that piece of information, I will make this as the answer. Thanks!